# insert data from html table to database jsp

Tags: html, sql, jsp

i have a jsp page . i display books from database. in front of all book i have order button. I want to order book . When i order bookcode and  bookname  will add
to database border table. but i cant get data from html table. How i can get data from html table in jsp file?

```
    st =conn.prepareStatement("select * from books where  book_name like ?  ");
            st.setString(1, "%"+book+"%");

            ResultSet rslt = st.executeQuery(); if(rslt.next()){   %>
<h3  align="center">Result Of Your Search  </h3>
<table align="center">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td>Book Name</td>
   <td>Author</td>
   <td>Title</td>
   <td>Code</td>
   <td>Page</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <% do { 
 %><tr>
    <td><%=rslt.getString("book_name")%></td>
     <td><%=rslt.getString("author")%></td>
      <td><%=rslt.getString("title")%></td>
       <td><%=rslt.getString("code")%></td>
    <td><%=rslt.getString("page")%></td> 
    <td><form method="POST" action=book.jsp>
        <input type="submit" value="order" name="order" /></form></td>
 <% } while (rslt.next()); %>


 </tbody>
</table>
```

'

i want when i click to  order button book name and book code will add to order database table

Comment: provide your code , it will be easy to understand

Comment: what dbms do you use? Provide sample code and the expected result.

Comment: Yes, as @Karthika suggested share the code which you have tried and what problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with two ways;

**Ajax Post Method** (recommended and popular way)

You can create a js which calls http post action to book.jsp and save your order without change page. *You have to learn how to post with ajax.*

**Form Post Method** (ehhh way)

When you create your table you have to define different forms with hidden input areas:

```
<% do { 
 %><tr>
    <form method="POST" action=book.jsp>
    <td><%=rslt.getString("book_name")%></td>
     <td><%=rslt.getString("author")%></td>
      <td><%=rslt.getString("title")%></td>
       <td><%=rslt.getString("code")%></td>
    <td><%=rslt.getString("page")%></td> 
    <td>
        <form method="POST" action=book.jsp>
<input type="hidden" value="<%=rslt.getString("book_name")%>" name="book_name" />
<input type="hidden" value="<%=rslt.getString("author")%>" name="author" />
<input type="hidden" value="<%=rslt.getString("code")%>" name="code" />
.
.
.
        <input type="submit" value="order" name="order" /></form></td>
    </form>
 <% } while (rslt.next()); %>
```

Then you can `use getParameter("book_name");`

### OR

Just add:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%=rslt.getString("id")%>" name="id" />
```

And you can;

```
`String id = request.getParameter("id");`
//Insert DB
```

Comment: this is my book.jsp  
     
    'String bname = request.getParameter("book_name");
     String code = request.getParameter("code");
     String sid=(String)session.getAttribute("STID"); 
    String bname = request.getParameter("book_name");
     String code = request.getParameter("code"); 
    String sid=(String)session.getAttribute("STID"); ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into order values(b_code.nextval,?,?,?,?,?,sysdate,sysdate+30)");
     ps.setString(2, "");
     ps.setString(1, sid);
     ps.setString(3, ""); ps.setString(4, bname);
     ps.setString(5, code);

Comment: Then create a dbBookSave.jsp and getParameters then insert your db.